# System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError

Tags: asp.net, sitefinity-4

We're running a Sitefinity 4.2 website on a windows server 2008 R2 server and we're getting a lot of exceptions (albeit not visible to the user). Many of the exceptions have the following in the stack trace: System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError

It will often refer to the connection to the host being closed.

Anyone know how we can troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

I did some searching in the Sitefinity forums and found this thread which you might find helpful: http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/forums/sitefinity-4-x/general-discussions/urgent-really-slow-after-editing-and-errors---in-production.aspx

it appears this may be related to an issue with memory usage in 4.2. I believe this has been resolved as of 4.4 and I would imagine that upgrading is probably the best way to address the issue.

I also believe the recommended path is 4.2 > 4.3 > 4.4 > 5.0. For more information on upgrading Sitefinity take a look at this blog post: http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/joshmorales/posts/11-03-02/upgrading_sitefinity_4_websites.aspx

I hope this is helpful!